# Designing social network structure for a mobile game

Tags: mobile, social

We are going to design a mobile game in which players could be related with each others in a social network-like mechanism. So, how we could integrate a mobile game and a social network (SN). Should we design a SN at first and then add game features to that or vice versa? Any suggestion?

Comment: so are you asking how to integrate a real social network into the game or how go about implementing a fake one that exists only in the game world?

Comment: If i get what you mean (Im trying to understand, but its like 9 in the morning and i just got to work) you want to create a social media style mobile app with games on it, that all link? So you would have a multi currency for across all games, challenges and compete against your friends? Show achievements on your Social Network page? if this is correct ill write an answer with a small guide on what i would do :)

Comment: @UriPopov, Primarily the mobile game should present a social network-like environment in which players could interact with each others in the form of chat, suggestions, etc. However, our ultimate goal is to connect this game-wide SN to the real ones such as Facebook.

Comment: @Ryanwhite, In fact, SN is considered as a feature of the game since it's a location based one. So, we want to make the game more realistic and  attractive so as players take it as both a game and a social network. However, your idea is interesting and we like to hear from you how to do that.

Comment: You would build an application that was essentially several games in one, that just link to several leader boards. Have one currency linked to the accounts and make players sign up, it sounds like allot of work but it wouldn't be that hard to do.

Comment: @Ryanwhite, Thanks for the guide, could you introduce me a mobile game alike what we want to build?

Comment: We could start a chat if you want to talk more about development? to avoid downvotes haha

Comment: @Ryanwhite, Sorry for delay! It seems better. I'll check my major questions and will arrange a chat with you :)